# How can I sum formula field in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, formula

I want to show my Grand Total values by using a specific formula field.
Actually I want to sum formula fiel such as :

> sum(@ClosingBalance)
>   But It gives a message 
>   This Field Can not be summarize

How can I solve this problem ??

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem,
I explain below how can I solve this,
I need two other function to show grand total in my report footer, where I use formula field as my summarized field.
so, firstly I create a function name @Grouptotal by using below formula

> Numbervar x:=x+{@ClosingBalance} And place it in my group footer

Then I create another formula name @GrandTotal and place it in my report footer

> Numbervar x:={@Grouptotal}-{@ClosingBalance}

Finally I suppress the @Grouptotal Field , and get the result of @GrandTotal By using Formula Field.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using variables.

**Step 1:** Create a Formula Field Named as **Sum1**:

```
Shared numberVar Sum1; 
Sum1 := (Your Table Field) + Sum1;
```

Place this one in Details section and suppress it (Right Click Formula --> Format Field --> Common --> Suppress).

**Step 2:** Create another formula to display the result as **PrintSum1**:

```
Shared numberVar Sum1;
Sum1;
```

Place this formula in Group Footer and suppress it (Right Click Formula --> Format Field --> Common --> Suppress).

**Step 3:** Create another formula field:

```
Shared numberVar GrandTotal;
GrandTotal := GrandTotal + {@Sum1}
```

This way you can summarize a formula field. Place this one in group footer.

**Step 4:** Create one last formula as **Clear**:

```
Shared numberVar Sum1;
Sum1 := 0;
```

Place this formula in Group Header and suppress it. This is to clear the Sum1 value for every record or group.

Let me know if you have issues.